# Get actual height of jQuery animated div and get this height to another animated div

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I want to get the actual height of animated div (A) and give it to another animated div (B).
The div A doesn't have a height obtained from CSS, the height is generated from padding.
The div B has a CSS height but i want to animate to get the same height of the div A.

This is what I did, but doesn't work:

```
$('#A').data(this, "inHeight", $(this).height()).animate({
    'padding-top' : 30
});
$('#B').animate({
    'height': div.data("inHeight")
}); 


$('#A').data(this, "outHeight", $(this).height()).animate({
    'padding-top' : 90
});
$('#B').animate({
    'height': div.data("outHeight")
});
```

Thanks for any help!

---

test: http://jsfiddle.net/A2bNm/

Comment: You do realize that `this` in that context probably is the window ?

Comment: in your animate functions, you have `div.data("inHeight")`. What is `div`? It's not defined here.

Comment: yes `div` is defined! `var div = $('#A');`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery.outerHeight()](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/)

> Description: Get the current computed height for the first element in the set of matched elements, including padding, border, and optionally margin. Returns an integer (without "px") representation of the value or null if called on an empty set of elements.

So you can try this:

```
$('#A').outerHeight(bool-include-margin);//get the div height
```

Comment: But how can i recall outerHeight to `$('#B')`? Thank you!